# Get similar effect like in fullpage.js slide option

Tags: slider, fullpage.js

Unfortunately, fullpage.js is not fitted for my needs in my project but I really liked the slide option where I can split my section into slides and and I can horizontally swith between these fullscreen slides, while remaining on the same section. Is there any other plugin to achieve the same result?

Comment: May I ask why fullPage.js doesn't fit your needs? Perhaps other solutions don't either?

Comment: I had problems with landscape orientation, I didn't wanted to create a different css file for landscape mode. Also I have a lot of content on some page, where a single full page is not enough. But I really liked the slide option, also I want to use it. Thats why I asked if is there any other solution for this.

Comment: For the landscape mode you can disable fullPage.js by using the `responsiveHeight` option and even the class `fp-auto-height-responsive` to avoid full-screen sections. 

For long content you can use the option `scrollOverflow` as [in this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).